# RFP Management system

Tags: document-management

I have a small business, where we often do proposals in response to RFP's (Request for Proposal, aka, Request for bid/information/solution, invitation to bid, etc.)
These often have a myriad of sections - they want introductions, resume's, and their various appendixes, cover sheets, spreadsheets, timetables, and other stuff.
Managing this in Word, GoogleDocs, or other word processor is difficult.

I am looking for a simple (preferably free or really cheap) system where I can take documents of various formats (like fillable PDF or spreadsheets) and drop them in a certain order, then finally combine them all into one document, or document set for submission.

- Page numbers, and a table of contents would be great.
- OS is not relevant. I have Mac, Windows, Linux, and I have a web browser.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a look at the [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/) document generation system originally written to document python but it can be *and is* used extenensivly for other document generation.

With it you can store a set of sections, e.g. Team Member CVs in [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) format and pull them together with a hierarchical structure from a single master page or [toctree](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.4.8/markup/toctree.html#toctree-directive) file with the order/structure as you need and then generate your final document.  You can define and use document styles and produce output in any or all of:

- HTML (including Windows HTML Help),
- LaTeX (for printable PDF versions),
- ePub,
- Texinfo,
- manual pages,
- plain text

With extensive cross references, tables of content, index, etc.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Available free for commercial use *BSD licence*
- Diagrams, plots and images can all be included.
- Installed under [python](https://www.python.org) which is itself gratis, cross platform and usable for commercial use.

I would also suggest using a [version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) such as Mercurial to allow you to store all of your versions of the specific pages while retaining the history of the changes.

Comment: +1 for mentioning a version control system. If the OP has so many documents part that he needs software to process it, he definitely needs version control.

Answer (score 0):

At work we use dokuwiki. It is not perfect, but works.

I use the wiki daily. There is a WYSIWYG plugin (but I don't like it and don't use it).

You get a simple history for each page: You see who has edited the page at what time and you can show a diff.

You get fulltext search. Maybe not for the content of PDF files, but for the textual wiki content.